# Automatic documentation of Fortran functions, modules and subroutines

Tags: documentation, fortran

Is there anything like [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) for documenting Fortran code? How does one document the API for the many functions they have so that they can find what they want more easily?

Comment: [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) has pretty reasonable Fortran support these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not "standard", but I've used a program called "robodoc" that is able to work with Fortran.

Nowadays I believe [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) supports Fortran as well, which IMHO is a better tool than robodoc.

Answer (score 0):

As janneb mentioned "robodoc" is clean, easy and hence useful. But you it will not analyze your program and you have to do everything yourself. On the other hand, Doxygen have incorporated the modern Fortran features(derived data types, type bound procedures, ... ) and just like C++ you can get an analysis of your program along with graphs etc.